# Implementing existing form in new form

Tags: javascript, html

A form (A) is generated by a party who provides our company with a sort of specialized CRM. A script references this form:
`<script src="https://example.com/source-of-form"></script>`

The form is too limited for our needs though. There's no API we can use.

Is there a way to incorporate form A in a new form (B), which would add the fields that are missing? These 'extra fields' would of course not end up in the 'CRM', but if this data can be mailed on submit we would be happy.

Is there a way to make this scenario happen?

Comment: You can get the fields from form A and just add to your new form with js then when submitting new form, only submit the CRM fields to the CRM and the rest you can choose to do whatever you want with

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? I'm still learning js... an example would be appreciated. Or perhaps you can point me to an online reference I can use.

Comment: You would need to be fairly familiar with js to do this. For me to explain something like this would be to write it all out. If you have a front end dev who is good with js you should ask that person for it